# Changing JQuery to affect colour of button, not background?

Tags: jquery, html, css

Just wondering how I can change the JQuery code so the background colour of the actual button goes orange, rather than the background of the element behind it?

Thanks

```css
@media only screen and (max-width : 700px ){
    .homepagemembershippricingtable {
        width: 100%;
  #margin-left: 10%;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
    }
}

.homepagemembershippricingtable {
 margin-top: 3%;
 border-spacing: 25px 0px;
 margin-bottom: 3%;
}

* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}

.homepagemembershippricingtable {
    float: left;
    width: 33.3%;
    padding: 12px;
}

.homemembershiptableheader {
 list-style-type: none;
    background-color: #29303f;
    color: #47ca6b;
    font-size: 40px;
 font-family: 'Fjalla One', sans-serif;
 transform: scale(1,1.1);
 padding: 3%;
 text-align: center;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 font-weight: 300;
 border-top-left-radius: 10px;
 border-top-right-radius: 10px;
 letter-spacing: 0.6px;
}

.homemembershiptableprice {
 list-style-type: none;
 color: #555;
 font-size: 15px;
 font-weight: 600;
 padding:3%;
 text-align: center;
}

.membershippricetext {
 list-style-type: none;
 font-size: 33px;
 color: #2f394d;
}

.homemembershiptablecredits {
 list-style-type: none;
 background-color: #f2f2f2;
 color: #555;
 font-size: 16px;
 font-weight: 600;
 padding: 4%;
 text-align: center;
}

@media only screen and (max-width : 700px ){
    .homepagemembershippricingtable {
        width: 100%;
  #margin-left: 10%;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
    }
    
    .hom
}

.membershipchoosebutton {
 background-color: #2f394d;
 padding: 5%;
 border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
 border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
 text-align: center;
    list-style: none;
}

.homepagemembershippricingtable {
    margin-bottom: 0;
    margin-bottom: 60px;
}

@media only screen and (max-width : 700px ){
    .homepagemembershippricingtable {
        margin-bottom: 10px;
    }
    
    .membershipoptionshometitle {
        margin-bottom: 30px;
        margin-top: 40px;
    }
    
    .homepagesignupbutton {
        margin-top: 40px
    }
    
    .welcomephototextsection h1 {
        margin-bottom: 10px;
    }
}

.chooseemembershipbutton {
 background-color: #2f394d;
 font-size: 16px;
 border: 1px solid #47ca6b;
 display: inline-block;
 padding: 10px 20px;;
 font-weight: 600;
 text-decoration: none;
    color: #47ca6b;
 border-radius: 10px;
 align-content: center;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>ExamMarked</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style6.css">
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="iconlogo.png">
<link rel="stylesheet" src="//normalize-css.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/normalize.css" />
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,400,600,700,800" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Fjalla+One" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

  $('.chooseemembershipbutton').click(function(){
    $('li.membershipchoosebutton').removeClass('bgGreen');
    $(this).parent().addClass('bgGreen');
  });

}); //end document.ready
</script>

<style>
    .bgGreen {
        background-color: orange;
    }
</style>

 
<div class="membershipoptionstablecontainer">
  <div class="homepagemembershippricingtable">
  <ul class="price">
    <li class="homemembershiptableheader">Silver</li>
    <li class="homemembershiptableprice"><p class="membershippricetext">£10</p> / month</li>
    <li class="homemembershiptablecredits">3 credits, monthly</li>
    <li class="membershipchoosebutton"><button type="button" class="chooseemembershipbutton" onclick="">Choose</button></td>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="homepagemembershippricingtable">
  <ul class="price">
    <li class="homemembershiptableheader">Gold</li>
    <li class="homemembershiptableprice"><p class="membershippricetext">£10</p> / month</li>
    <li class="homemembershiptablecredits">3 credits, monthly</li>
    <li class="membershipchoosebutton"><button type="button" class="chooseemembershipbutton" onclick="">Choose</button></td>
  </ul>
</div>
```

"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."

"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This:

$(this).parent().addClass('bgGreen');

Just needs to changed to:

$(this).addClass('bgGreen');

So that the code isn't changing the button's parent container but the button itself.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

  $('.chooseemembershipbutton').click(function(){
    //Choose the button specific class and remove all orange backgrouns
    $('.chooseemembershipbutton').removeClass('bgGreen');
    
    //This line needs to change so it doesn't add the class to the button's parent:
    //Set this button now
    $(this).addClass('bgGreen');
  });

}); //end document.ready
```

```css
@media only screen and (max-width : 700px ){
    .homepagemembershippricingtable {
        width: 100%;
  #margin-left: 10%;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
    }
}

.homepagemembershippricingtable {
 margin-top: 3%;
 border-spacing: 25px 0px;
 margin-bottom: 3%;
}

* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}

.homepagemembershippricingtable {
    float: left;
    width: 33.3%;
    padding: 12px;
}

.homemembershiptableheader {
 list-style-type: none;
    background-color: #29303f;
    color: #47ca6b;
    font-size: 40px;
 font-family: 'Fjalla One', sans-serif;
 transform: scale(1,1.1);
 padding: 3%;
 text-align: center;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 font-weight: 300;
 border-top-left-radius: 10px;
 border-top-right-radius: 10px;
 letter-spacing: 0.6px;
}

.homemembershiptableprice {
 list-style-type: none;
 color: #555;
 font-size: 15px;
 font-weight: 600;
 padding:3%;
 text-align: center;
}

.membershippricetext {
 list-style-type: none;
 font-size: 33px;
 color: #2f394d;
}

.homemembershiptablecredits {
 list-style-type: none;
 background-color: #f2f2f2;
 color: #555;
 font-size: 16px;
 font-weight: 600;
 padding: 4%;
 text-align: center;
}

@media only screen and (max-width : 700px ){
    .homepagemembershippricingtable {
        width: 100%;
  #margin-left: 10%;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
    }
    
    .hom
}

.membershipchoosebutton {
 background-color: #2f394d;
 padding: 5%;
 border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
 border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
 text-align: center;
    list-style: none;
}

.homepagemembershippricingtable {
    margin-bottom: 0;
    margin-bottom: 60px;
}

@media only screen and (max-width : 700px ){
    .homepagemembershippricingtable {
        margin-bottom: 10px;
    }
    
    .membershipoptionshometitle {
        margin-bottom: 30px;
        margin-top: 40px;
    }
    
    .homepagesignupbutton {
        margin-top: 40px
    }
    
    .welcomephototextsection h1 {
        margin-bottom: 10px;
    }
}

.chooseemembershipbutton {
 background-color: #2f394d;
 font-size: 16px;
 border: 1px solid #47ca6b;
 display: inline-block;
 padding: 10px 20px;;
 font-weight: 600;
 text-decoration: none;
    color: #47ca6b;
 border-radius: 10px;
 align-content: center;
}

.bgGreen {
  background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>ExamMarked</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style6.css">
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="iconlogo.png">
<link rel="stylesheet" src="//normalize-css.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/normalize.css" />
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,400,600,700,800" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Fjalla+One" rel="stylesheet">


<div class="membershipoptionstablecontainer">
  <div class="homepagemembershippricingtable">
  <ul class="price">
    <li class="homemembershiptableheader">Silver</li>
    <li class="homemembershiptableprice"><p class="membershippricetext">£10</p> / month</li>
    <li class="homemembershiptablecredits">3 credits, monthly</li>
    <li class="membershipchoosebutton"><button type="button" class="chooseemembershipbutton" onclick="">Choose</button></td>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="homepagemembershippricingtable">
  <ul class="price">
    <li class="homemembershiptableheader">Gold</li>
    <li class="homemembershiptableprice"><p class="membershippricetext">£10</p> / month</li>
    <li class="homemembershiptablecredits">3 credits, monthly</li>
    <li class="membershipchoosebutton"><button type="button" class="chooseemembershipbutton" onclick="">Choose</button></td>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: THANK YOU, the only thing is unlike the version I posted this lets you have both buttons change colour at once.. I only want the user to have one selected at once?

Comment: I've edited the above code snipped to only allow a single selection.  Not sure why it got down-voted necessarily but it probably showed up in someone's review queue.  They're normally supposed to leave a comment if they down-vote though.

Comment: Ok thanks for your help on this :).. yes it just annoying when your just trying ask for help, and people downvote like I don't think there's any issue with my question?.. Especially when they can't even leave criticism to say what the issue was in the first place! anyways sorry for the rant

Comment: No worries.  If this all works for you please mark it as answered so it drops out of the unanswered queue when you get a chance.